# How to nest generators

Tags: python, generator

I'm looking into generators to make some of my code more efficient. Currently wondering how I can/should handle nested for loops that each create a list. The nested loop re-generates a list of values for every step of the for loop. These values are a vector normalization of 3 columns of the fed data.  From this list a max value is taken and added to the list that is returned by the function. 
Seems this could be made much more efficient by using generators. I'm not sure however how to handle the nested for loop as the function will stop on the first yield.

Code as it is currently;

```
def define_max_values(data, indexes):

    max_values = []

    for iter in range(len(indexes)):
        data_index_window = data[index[iter] - 5:index[iter] + 50]
        for i in range(len(data_index_window)):
            sub_list = []   
            sub_list.append(np.linalg.norm(data_index_window.iloc[i, 0:3].values))

        max_values.append(max(sub_list))
    return max_values
```

I think this could be turned into this, using 1 generator

```
def define_max_values(data, indexes):
     for iter in range(len(indexes)):
            data_index_window = data[index[iter] - 5:index[iter] + 50]
            for i in range(len(data_index_window)):
                sub_list = []
                sub_list.append(np.linalg.norm(data_index_window.iloc[i, 0:3].values))

            yield(max(sub_list)
```

This seems more readable/efficient code already, but wondering if/how I could replace the inner list.append with another yield.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your indentation - the inner `for` loop seems indented one level too far, as the `data_index_window` line in front of it doesn't start a new code block. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: you are correct. mistake I made when trying to get the code formatted properly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` doesn't need a sequence, it can be used with generators as well, something like:

```
def define_max_values(data, indexes):
    for iter in range(len(indexes)):
        data_index_window = data[index[iter] - 5:index[iter] + 50]
        yield max(np.linalg.norm(
                          data_index_window.iloc[i, 0:3].values) \
                  for i in range(len(data_index_window)))
```